# Only share one folder in document library with authenticated external user?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, share, item-level-permissions

I have subsite where I wish an external authenticated user only can see one folder in a document library.

I dont want him to see the subsite

I dont want him to see 8 folders in a document library ("Documents")

I want him to see one folder in the same document library ("Documents")

Is this possible? If so how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If this is in SharePoint online, you can share the unique link using share(you will find the option) that only external user will be allowed to see

Comment: Yes, but I want the user to be autheticated/logged in to make it secure. Inside the folder it is also possible to go up a level, and there is also a link to the subsite frontpage. But the registered/authenticated user should not be able to access this. Only this one folder....

Answer (score 0):

Try to share with "Require Sign-In" to achieve your requirement.

There is an article about sharing on SharePoint Online, you can take a look at:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Share-sites-or-documents-with-people-outside-your-organization-80e49744-e30f-44db-8d51-16661b1d4232

"Share a document requiring sign in to your site" section

Answer (score 0):

The UX for everyone usually suffers when dealing with folder level permissions . I agree that it sounds like a good idea when the business requests it, most likely because they are used to file shares. However it oftens gets messy pretty fast as people starts using the library, so perhaps it would be a better idea to use two libraries, one for internal docs and another for shared files?